# How do I stop Django from adding path before links?

Tags: html, django, templates, view, hyperlink

Django insists on adding the current path before a link i put into an a> tag on my page : example:

```
 <h6><a href="{{ officialUrl }}">Read More</a></h6>
```

now assuming officialUrl was "www.google.com" - Django will instead link to "http://www.mysite.com/this/page/www.google.com"

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is not doing that, browsers do because you are not specifying a protocol. A proper link inside an `<a>` tag will usually begin with `http://` or some other `XXX://` protocol. Simply putting `www.google.com` is not a proper link.

Comment: An *external* link will start http:// or similar, but not internal links. I'm sure you know that, but the OP might not.

Answer (score 1):

`www.google.com` isn't a URL.

`http://www.google.com/` is.

Since the former isn't a URL, your browser (note, your browser, and not Django - look at the HTML output to confirm this) will assume it's relative to the current page.